# how to position inner thumbnails in same position of container, simple html issue

Tags: html, css

i have simple issue with HTML positions 
in the following code i have one wrapper div> Container in this div 
i have 2 more divs name is side_bar_wrap and left_wrap in left_wrap div i have 
4 thumbnails divs name are same as thumbnails my issue is how can i align this 4 thumbnails div with space between right and left but no on first and last div of this group

following is my code, please help me..

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
.container 
{
    width:100%;
    max-width:1170px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

* 
{
    margin:0;   
    padding:0;
}

.side_bar_wrap
{
    width:29%;     
    height:300px;
    background:#148b23;
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
    float:left;
}

.left_wrap 
{
    width:70%;
    float:right;
}


.thumbnails{
width: 22%;
margin: 0 11px;

position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #cfcfcf;
    float:left;
}

.inner_task 
{

}


.clear
{
    clear:both;
}
```

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
<div class="container">


        <div style="width:29%; float:left; height:400px; background:gray; margin:40px 11px 40px 0;"></div>

        <div style="width:70%;float:left; height:400px; background:gray; margin:40px 0;"></div>

        <div class="side_bar_wrap"></div>
        <div class="left_wrap">
            <div class="thumbnails">
                <div class="inner_thumb">
                    <div style="width:100%; height:200px; background:#efefef;"></div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="thumbnails">
                <div class="inner_thumb">
                    <div style="width:100%; height:200px; background:#efefef;"></div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="thumbnails">
                <div class="inner_thumb">
                    <div style="width:100%; height:200px; background:#efefef;"></div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="thumbnails">
                <div class="inner_thumb">
                    <div style="width:100%; height:200px; background:#efefef;"></div>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div style="width:100%; float:left; height:400px; background:gray; margin:40px 0;"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Create a fiddle using jsfiddle.net. That would help to understand your question more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first-child and last-child that css provides for you

Basically first-child allow you to make style changes to the first div, and last-child allows you to make changes to the last div

so something like this:

```css
.thumnails:first-child {
  /*NO SPACE ON ONE SIDE*/
  margin-left:0px;
  
 }
.thumnails:last-child {
  /*NO SPACE ON ONE SIDE*/
  margin-right:0px;
  
 }
```

If you want advance alittle more you can use :nth-child(), for when you you want to change the style of the third div or whatever, so

```css
.thumnails:nth-child(3) {
  background-color:#ff0000;  
}
```